# Arc with radius between 2 points

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to find out how to draw an arc with OpenGL between 2 points with a given radius.Is there any way to do this in OpenGL or to find the center point where I need to draw the arc so the both points get connected with the given radius ? :)

Attached screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvsRR.png

Comment: So you would know how to draw your arc if you were given the center point rather than two points!?

Comment: Yes I’m a little bit confused how to do this with 2 points because I’m always drawing an arc or a circle with a center point and a given radius :)

Comment: Well, just given two points alone, the problem is actually underdetermined. There are two possible circles passing through those two points. Typically, a convention based on winding order is used to define which of the two possibilities is supposed to be picked.

Comment: Apart from that, it's still unclear to me what exactly you're asking…

Comment: Are you asking for how to draw an arc that spans between two given points and overlaps a circle of a given radius?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple, but complete and tested opengl program that demonstrates what it sounds like you are looking for.  Note that there is not a single answer to the question of what is the arc between two points at radius x, since the arc can bend in either of two directions.

Pay careful attention to the *second* **createArc** function overload as this represents the core of the answer, though it calls the *first* **createArc** function overload to finish the job.

EDIT: I've realized that I did not account for the ambiguity of "arc between two angles" in my earlier answer (arc from 0 to 90 could be direct or all the way around).  I've updated the code to define whether you are interested in the smaller arc or the larger arc.

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

const int ARC_VERTEX_COUNT = 100;

// Don't use global variables at home, kids!
GLFWwindow* window;
GLuint shader;
GLint shaderLoc_pos;
GLuint vbo_circle;
GLuint vbo_arc;

float normalizeAngleToSmallestPositive(float angle) {
    while (angle < 0.0) { angle += M_PI*2; }
    while (angle >= M_PI*2) { angle -= M_PI*2; }
    return angle;
}

bool startApp() {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        return false;
    }
    window = glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return false;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewInit();
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glLineWidth(10.0);
    return true;
}

void stopApp() {
    glfwTerminate();
}

void createShader() {
    const char* vsSrc =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "in vec2 pos; void main() { gl_Position = vec4(pos, 0.0, 1.0); }";
    const char* fsSrc =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "out vec4 color; void main() { color = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.5); }";

    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vsSrc, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vs);

    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fsSrc, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fs);

    shader = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shader, vs);
    glAttachShader(shader, fs);
    glLinkProgram(shader);

    shaderLoc_pos = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "pos");
}

// Create an arc between two given angles, based on the circle described by the given radius and
// center point
GLuint createArc(float angle1, float angle2, float radius, float x, float y, float useBiggerArc) {
    // Prepare angles
    angle1 = normalizeAngleToSmallestPositive(angle1);
    angle2 = normalizeAngleToSmallestPositive(angle2);
    if (angle1 > angle2) {
        float buffer = angle1;
        angle1 = angle2;
        angle2 = buffer;
    }
    if (useBiggerArc != angle2-angle1 > M_PI) {
        angle1 += M_PI*2;
    }

    // Create opengl geometry
    GLfloat pos[ARC_VERTEX_COUNT * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < ARC_VERTEX_COUNT; i++) {
        pos[i*2] = sin((float)i / (ARC_VERTEX_COUNT-1) * (angle2 - angle1) + angle1) * radius + x;
        pos[i*2+1] = cos((float)i / (ARC_VERTEX_COUNT-1) * (angle2 - angle1) + angle1) * radius + y;
    }
    GLuint result;
    glGenBuffers(1, &result);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, result);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pos), pos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    return result;
}

GLuint createCircle(float radius, float x, float y) {
    return createArc(M_PI*0, M_PI*2, radius, x, y, true);
}

// Create an arc between two given points that is based on a circle with the given radius.
GLuint createArc(
    float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float radius, bool arcDirection, bool useBiggerArc)
{
    // distance between points
    float distance = sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
    // halfway point
    float xAverage = (x1+x2)/2.0;
    float yAverage = (y1+y2)/2.0;
    // circle center
    float xCenter = sqrt(radius*radius - distance*distance/4.0) * (y1-y2) / distance;
    float yCenter = sqrt(radius*radius - distance*distance/4.0) * (x2-x1) / distance;
    xCenter = xAverage + (arcDirection ? xCenter : -xCenter);
    yCenter = yAverage + (arcDirection ? yCenter : -yCenter);
    // angles
    float angle1 = atan2(x1-xCenter, y1-yCenter);
    float angle2 = atan2(x2-xCenter, y2-yCenter);
    // create the arc
    return createArc(angle1, angle2, radius, xCenter, yCenter, useBiggerArc);
}

void runMainLoop() {
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shader);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderLoc_pos);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_circle);
        glVertexAttribPointer(shaderLoc_pos, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, ARC_VERTEX_COUNT);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_arc);
        glVertexAttribPointer(shaderLoc_pos, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, ARC_VERTEX_COUNT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

int main(void) {
    if (startApp())
    {
        createShader();
        vbo_circle = createCircle(0.75, 0.0, 0.0);
        vbo_arc = createArc(0.0, 0.75, 0.75, 0.0, 0.75, false, false);

        runMainLoop();
        stopApp();
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Than you very much that works perfect :) My initial intention was because I'm developing a Navigation system to draw everything on a display and you need a distance (DTA) to make the turn for the next course so you don't overshoot the waypoints like I've shown in my screenshot in Post 1.I know the distance so where to start drawing the arc to the next waypoint and I know the Radius for the Circle.Hopefully I can finish my project with your code :D

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a maths question, I feel.

If you have the coordinates of the two points suppose:
[image: formula]

and the given radius is  'R'

then the coordinates of the centre, say  [image: formula1] can be calculated using

[image: formula2]

where

[image: formula3]
,

[image: formula]

there shall be two centres, one for an upward arc and another for a downward arc.
the other centre can be found through

[image: foo]

now, you can find the inverse cosine using the `acos()` function included in the `<cmath>` library.